# Missing assembly reference for SqlConnection

Tags: dapper, sqlclient

I'm still new to MVC and dapper ORM.
Suppose I use dapper for MVC and and when I try to build solution, it showing message:
'SqlConnection does not contain a definition for'Query' and no extension method 'Query' accepting a first argument of type 'SqlConnection'.

here is the code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;



  public string Connectionstring = @"Data Source = KL - PT - 049\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog = Record; Integrated Security = True";

    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring))

        {

            conn.Open();
            var customer = conn.**Query**<Customer>("Select * from Customer");
            return customer;
        }
```

my question is: does the Query above should be fine if I use that way? since I already use data.sqlClient reference?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
using Dapper;
```

at the top of the file.

Note: in recent versions of Visual Studio you can also just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> on the unresolved extension method and it will offer to fix it for you:

[image]